# Why doesn't IGrouping inherit IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> like IDictionary?

Tags: c#

IGrouping:

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, 
IEnumerable
```

IDictionary:

```
public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable
```

So, `IDictionary` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` while `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`. If the elements of `IGrouping` contain keys, why does the interface not also use `KeyValuePair`? It also seems like methods implemented in `IDictionary` that would be useful for `IGrouping` such as `IDictionary.ContainsKey` are unavailable in `IGrouping`, meaning any attempt to find a key on a group (in O(1) time) would look something like:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 1};
var grp = myList.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
if (grp.ContainsKey(someValue)){...}
```

Am I just using `IGrouping` wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find if a particular `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` contains a particular `TKey`, just check its `Key` property directly. No need for a loop.

`GroupBy` doesn't return `IGrouping`, it returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<...>>`. That is, `IGrouping` represents the results for one single key value, and you get multiple such results. It cannot return `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, as `GroupBy` preserves key order, and `Dictionary` doesn't. No other pre-existing collection type is appropriate here.

Since you don't care about key order, and also don't care about the individual values for each key (since they're identical), you can store your results in a dictionary yourself, like you're doing now. You're doing the right thing.

If you don't need the counts, you can also use a `HashSet<int>`.

If you end up needing the individual values, you can also use `ToLookup`.